# Need to install OpenliteSpeed Server on Fedora 31

Tags: installation, fedora

I am trying to install OpenliteSpeed server on Fedora 31. There are no binaries available so I thought of compiling the source code. Am following instructions from this page: https://openlitespeed.org/kb/installation-from-source-code/

but I am getting errors at the make & make install step.

This is the error I get:

```
$ make && make install
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/navjot/openlitespeed-1.6.4/src'
Makefile:760: .deps/xxhash.Po: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '.deps/xxhash.Po'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/navjot/openlitespeed-1.6.4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:409: all-recursive] Error 1
```

I was suggested that I should use the ./build.sh file first. Tried that and I got the following error:

```
No match for argument: epel-release
Error: Unable to find a match: epel-release
This script only works on 6/7/8 for centos family._Static_assert
```

Does anyone know how to proceed? I can't figure out any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow [this method](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/install-from-binary/) to install from compiled binary. 
Download the OpenLiteSpeed binary from the [Download page](https://openlitespeed.org/downloads/) or use the `wget` command to download it from the console, here we use v1.6.4 as example:

```
wget https://openlitespeed.org/packages/openlitespeed-1.6.4.tgz
```

Installation

```
tar -zxvf openlitespeed-*.tgz
cd openlitespeed
./install.sh
```

Now you can start the web server, like so:

```
/usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl start
```

Check the status:

```
/usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl status
```

Last, don't forget to install libnsl network service package when you are on CentOS 8 or Fedora system.

```
sudo dnf install libnsl -y
```